# HTML5 Video not Working on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I can't seem to get the HTML5 video working on the latest version of Mozilla Firefox. It's working on Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari. Here's the source code

```
<video id="video" muted autoplay poster="uploads/toaf-video.jpg" controls loop="loop">
 <source src="uploads/toaf2014.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had an additional format OGV and WebM.

Comment: @AamirShahzad yep. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try supplying multiple formats to overcome format compatibility differences in different browsers.

```
<video id="video" muted autoplay poster="uploads/toaf-video.jpg" controls loop="loop">
  <source src="uploads/toaf2014.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="uploads/toaf2014.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="uploads/toaf2014.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**Why Different formats?**

1. Firefox 3.5+, Opera 10.5+ and Chrome 3+ support `ogv`
2. Firefox 4+, Opera 10.6+ and Chrome 6+ support WebM (and ogv,
   assuming they don’t drop support in future)

Or Use the flash video to support all major browsers.